# RMarkdown Officedown: Insert svg image to word document

Tags: r, svg, r-markdown, knitr, officedown

Is it possible to insert a svg image to a word document (.docx)?

This is my YAML:

```
---
title: "SVG Image"
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---
```

For jpg images, the following code works perfectly:

````
```{r, fig.cap = "cap", fig.id = "id"}
include_graphics("path to my picture/picture.jpg")
``
````

However, if i do the same for a svg image, the image doesn't show in the produced word document.